# How I can configure flat file name as filename_*.txt in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flatfilesource

I have flat file source and connection manager. I need to configure its connection string as filename_* .txt. I have one variable on package level to read the directory path and then I am using it in expression property to read the file path as @FilePath + "filename__* " + ".txt". This is not working. I am not able to figure out how to configure file name as filename_*.txt.

Comment: *"This is not working."* This doesn't tell us anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this best practice is to use a foreach loop container of type File Enumerator, you can pass it a search string to scan for files and run a process using the found file name.

Note if you have multiple files in that folder it will run the same process for each file

[image: For Each Container of type File Enumerator]

The container will then execute everything inside it for each file found with that search string. You will need to map the found file name to a variable on the Variable Mapping section.

[image: Map Variable]

You can now use the variable as an expression in your file connection

Your control flow should look like this

[image: Control Flow]

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem. :)